# docker nginx+php-fpm: Environment variable working on console but not in script

Tags: docker, environment-variables

i'm using an ubuntu:18.04 container with nginx and php-fpm7.2. I set

```
clear_env=no
```

in */etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf* and

```
variables_order = "EGPCS"
```

in */etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini*

I pass pass a variable $myVar from docker-compose. Running

```
echo $myVar
```

shows the correct value.

Running 
    php -r "echo getenv('myVar');"
shows me the correct value.

Placing a file *index.php* into */var/www/html/* (this is my www root) containing

```
<?php
   echo getenv('myVar');
?>
```

returns me an empty string.

Can someone help me?

Thank you, Martin

Comment: Which is the user running `php-fpm`? Is it the one you're logged in when you invoke `php -r "echo getenv('myVar');"` via command-line?

Answer (score 7):

This is a PHP-FPM prank.

- Setup the `clear_env = no` on `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, so;

On Dockerfile start de php-fpm with `init.d`, **not use** `service`.
Ex:

```
CMD /etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm start && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Check environment variables now

Answer (score -2):

It's possible that the naming convention, more specifically, the separator is causing the issue. Try naming your env var MY_VAR instead of MyVar.